# I want get comment from an excel sheet protected with python using xlwings, but it returns None

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I want get comment from an excel sheet protected with python using xlwings, but it returns None, even though it has a comment

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw


PATH = 'C:/Users/Hendo/Pictures/Sample.xlsx'
psw = '1234'
wb = xw.Book(PATH, password= psw)
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
print(sheet.range('H15').note)
print(sheet.range('H15').value)
```

It prints:

```
None
AAAA
```

I hope to return the cells comment(s)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pywin32 interface and try changing your code to

```py
import xlwings as xw


PATH = 'C:/Users/Hendo/Pictures/Sample.xlsx'
psw = '1234'

wb = xw.Book(PATH, password=psw)
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

print(sheet.range('H15').api.Comment.Text())
print(sheet.range('H15').value)
```

Other method
This will Print all comments on all Sheets in the workbook.

```
import xlwings as xw


excel_file = 'C:/Users/Hendo/Pictures/Sample.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)

    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        print(f"----Sheet '{sheet.name}'------------")
        for cmt in sheet.api.Comments:
            print(f"Comment Co-ordinate: {cmt.Parent.Address.replace('$', '')}")
            print(f"Comment Author: {cmt.Author}")
            print(f"Comment Text: {sheet.range(cmt.Parent.Address).api.Comment.Text()}")
            print("----------------")
```

Comment: It didn't work, the file has several spreadsheets inside it, I copied the spreadsheet I wanted to a new file and it worked. But I still can't do it for a file with multiple sheets

Comment: Should not make any difference how many sheets or number of comments on the Sheet unless perhaps you run out of memory or there is another issue with the workbook or maybe zombie instances of the workbook. Copying a Sheet to another workbook would reduce the overhead and remove any underlying issue the original workbook has.

Comment: I have included another code sample to loop through all Sheets in the workbook and print all the details on comments on each Sheet, Co-ordinates, Author and the text. This example uses a context manager so it ensures that the Excel instance is closed when the code exits and the should be no zombie instances left open it that's happening. Ultimately this is pretty much it so if it still a problem your workbook(s) then Xlwings may be no good to you.